# How to run launch file in ROS from C++ .cpp file

Tags: c++, ros, launch

I would like to know how can I run launch file using a c++ file. I want to run different launch file depending on the if statement.

```
if(case1){
 run launch_file_1.launch}
if(case2){
 run launch_fie_2.launch}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated meta-comment: `launch` is an extremely poorly defined tag. I'm not sure if you're using it correctly because I'm not sure it CAN be used correctly.

Comment: @user4581301 they are definitely not using it correctly. OP assumed it was a tag for a ROS tool; which it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the cstdlib library we can do this. You are basically creating a command line command using c++

```
#include <cstdlib> // for system()
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      // Call roslaunch command to run your launch file
      std::string launch_file_path = "/path/to/your/launch/file.launch"; // Replace with the path to your actual launch file
      std::string command = "roslaunch " + launch_file_path;
      int result = system(command.c_str());
      if (result == -1)
      {
        ROS_ERROR("Failed to execute roslaunch command");
        return 1;
      }
    
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A quick note on `system`: Check with the implementation documentation to ensure that the return value means what you expect it to mean. Because C++ supports a wide variety of targets, the Standard leaves the details up to the folks implementing the library for a specific target.

Answer (score 0):

There is no roslaunch API for C++, unlike with Python. To actually run a launch file you'd need to use `system` to create a new process directly; I'm not sure I'd actually recommend this solution, though.

```
if(some_bool){
    system("source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash | roslaunch some_launch_file.launch")
}
```